# Matrix of orthogonalprojection

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, orthogonality

whats the matrix of an orthogonalprojection?

This question was part of a longer task:

1. Step: two vectors were given:

   - $v_1 = (i, 0, 1)$
   - $v_2 = (0,i,1)$

U is a vector space, spanned by v1 and v2

2. Step: Determine a orthonormalbasis (via gram-schmid) of U
3. Step: complement this basis to an orthonormalbasis of $\mathbb{C}3$.
4. Step: What is the coordinate-matrix (relating to the basis of Step 3) for the orthogonalprojection onto U?

??

Answer (score 1):

Orthogonal projection is in this such a linear thansformation, that if you have basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ of $U$ and orthogonal basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ then for all $x=av_1+bv_2+cv_3 \in \mathbb{C}^3$:

$$P(x)=av_1+bv_2$$

So $PV_1=v_1$, $Pv_2=v_2$ and $Pv_3=0$ and finally:

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Hi - thank you very much. What would I do, if I had to project the vector (-1, 3, -1) orthogonal on the subspace given by $v_1 = (8, -24, 0)$ and $v_2 = (-24, 72, 25)$ ?

Comment: Note that vector $v_3=(3,1,0)$ is orthogonal to $\text{span}(v_1,v_2)$. Next you should write $(-1,3,-1)$ as $av_1+bv_2+cv_3$. Orthogonal projection will be $av_1+bv_2$.

Comment: Hi - so I have $(-1,3,-1) = -\frac{49}{200}v_1 - \frac{1}{25}v_2 + 0v_3$. So the orthogonal projection is the vector $(-1, 3, -1)$ itself ?

Comment: Yes, if your computation is correct, then $(-1,3,-1) \in \text{span}\{v_1,v_2\}$, so its orthogonal projection is itself (it's true for all $W \in \text{span}\{v_1,v_2\}$).